# Unity 3D script player shoot bad direction

Tags: frame-rate

I'm using Unity 3d version 4 because I have a MacOS X and I'm making a FPS 3D
I have a script to make the player shoot but this script only shoots up and does not consider where I point the mouse
Below the code in CS
Could someone please correct my script because I have been blocked for 3 days and I have not found any solution on the Internet. Thanks

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
 
public class ShootDemo : MonoBehaviour {
 
    public Rigidbody projectile;
 
    public float speed = 100;
 
 
 
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
   
    }
   
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
 
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Rigidbody instantiatedProjectile = Instantiate(projectile,
                                                           transform.position,
                                                           transform.rotation)
                as Rigidbody;
 
            instantiatedProjectile.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(0, 0,speed));
 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you set the velocity is not right, you should get the mouse position like this:

```
        Rigidbody instantiatedProjectile = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        var input = Input.mousePosition;
        input.z = 10;
        Vector2 touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(input);
        Vector2 dir =  new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y) - touchPos;
        dir.Normalize();
        instantiatedProjectile.velocity = dir * speed;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this script in JavaSript working but the bullet speed is too slow and then the bullet stays in the scene for 2 seconds instead of making it disappear completely. How can I then add strength to the bullet?

```
  var Effect : Transform;
var TheDamage = 100;
 
function Update ()
{
   
    var hit : RaycastHit;
    var ray : Ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Vector3(Screen.width*0.5, Screen.height*0.5, 0));
   
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, hit, 100))
        {
            var particleClone = Instantiate(Effect, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));
            Destroy(particleClone.gameObject, 2);
            hit.transform.SendMessage("ApplyDamage", TheDamage, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
        }
    }
   
}
```